# How do I get the promise values of blue bird's Promise.settle()?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

When I use Promise.map() I either get an array of user_ids or a single error. When I use Promise.settle() I get the values of the array and not the values from the promises returned in the array. I'm using the following to better illustrate what I mean:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var user_names = ['John','Mary'];

Promise.map(user_names, function(name){
    //following will return a promise resolved with the db id
    // or a rejection
    return db.create(name);
}).then(function(user_ids){
    //if db.create never failed I get an array of db ids
    console.log(user_ids); //returns ['1','2']
}).catch(function(err){
    //at least one of the db.create() failed
});

Promise.settle(user_names, function(name){
    //following will return a promise resolved with the db id
    // or a rejection
    return db.create(name);
}).then(function(results){
    //I get an array of PromiseInspection objects
    if(results[0].isFulfilled()){
        var value = results[0].value();
        console.log(value); //returns 'John'
    }
});
```

My ultimate goal is to get back an array of ids. That array might be smaller than the array `user_names` due to the possibility of a promise being rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Promise.settle`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#settle---promise) does work like `Promise.all`, not like `Promise.map`. It does *not take an array of values and a callback*, it does take an array of promises (and if given values, it resolves them to promises). Your callback is simply ignored.

You will have call the function yourself, using [Array's `.map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
Promise.settle(user_names.map(function(name) {
//                       ^^^^^
    return db.create(name);
})).then(function(results) {
    if (results[0].isFulfilled()) {
        var value = results[0].value();
        console.log(value); // returns the database id now
    }
});
```

Comment: EXCELLENT! I tested it with my existing code and it does what I want.